# Discrepancy between binomial and nCr methods of calculating probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

A bag has 1000 balls, some colored red, and the rest green. The fraction of red-colored balls in the bag is 0.2. A blindfolded observer picks out 5 balls from this bag. What is the probability that 3 reds are picked?

Method 1:

The probability *p* of picking a red ball is 0.2. So, this can be treated as a binomial problem: 
$ Pr$(3 red balls picked) $= {5 \choose 3} (0.2)^3 (0.8)^2 = 0.0512$

Method 2:

We choose 3 red balls from a group of 200 and 2 green ones from the group of 800. So, the probability becomes:

$ \frac{{200 \choose 3} {800 \choose 2}} {{1000 \choose 5}} \approx 0.0508785...$

Why is there a slight discrepancy in the probabilities? Is it an artifact of my calculator's limitations or am I missing something deeper?

Comment: Your first binomial method looks like sampling *with* replacement and your second hypergeometric  method *without* replacement.  The numbers for your second method would be very different if you had started with $10$ balls (so $2$ red balls out of $10$ in the bag and a probability of $0$ of choosing $3$ red balls)

Comment: The second method uses the *hypergeometric distribution* which is the correct one to be used when sampling is without replacement, though the binomial approximation can be used if (just as a thumb rule)  the population size is more than $20$ times the sample size.

Comment: The fraction of the $1000$ balls that are red being $0.2$, *does not* mean that each red ball has an *independent* probability for being red of $0.2$. It means that $200$ among those balls are red.  So it is only correct to use the second method.

Comment: It should be emphasized that those final answers you got were *close* to one another... and being *close* is sometimes good enough.  If rather than $1000$ balls you were picking from $10000$ the answers would be even closer and if we weren't told the number of balls and we were merely told or led to assume that there were just "a very large number" of balls, then the binomial distribution would have been good enough for our purposes.  The error being too small to matter.  It would not have been exact however.